# How to close user session on browser closure without onunload and onbeforeunload functions

Tags: javascript, servlets

I want to know how the banking websites  close the user session on browser closure.And which one of the following will be a good option for that and how can it be done.
1. Sending a keep-alive message to the login servlet inorder to extend the session timeout.
2. Using httpsessionbindinglistener to bound and unbound a user object.
Thanks in advance ... With hope ☺

Comment: I'm using both java and JavaScript in my application

Comment: It all depends on your server tech stack and how you are keeping the session "alive" to begin with.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: You missed the point. The point is that you need to be more specific. You have told us nothing of your server side technology and how it's being used. For instance if you were using PHP on your server (which I doubt you are) then it's as simple as setting `session.cookie_lifetime` to 0. 1) What are you using  on your server. 2) how are session lifetimes manipulated in that tech?

Comment: Oops!... Mine is a java web application,server side I'm using Java and client side I'm using JSP JavaScript.